# How to wrap a word with curly braces or quotation marks instead of erasing it? - Python using Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'm starting to learn Python using Visual Studio and something that is bugging me out is that, when I select a variable and press `"` or `{`, instead of wrapping it and leaving it like `"variable"` or `{variable}`, it just erases the variable and leaves behind the `"` or the `{`.

Is there any way to configure Visual Studio so it does what I want?

Comment: I assume you *don't* want the latter (which is the current behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Look for "Auto Surround" in the "Preferences - Settings" (it has a search box).

I has several settings to determine when it should be applied, one of them is "never".

[image: Screenshot showing Auto Surround in the settings]

If it is set to `languageDefined`, it's possible it's not set up for the language you're writing in, or disabled specifically for that.